# is it possible to get notified when lxc container (unprivileged) is stopped

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, lxc

I want to run simple shell script when lxc container is stopped.
I try to use 
`lxc.hook.post-stop = script` I want to execute
in my lxc container config file,
but the script is not being invoked when the lxc container is stopped.

Is there any other way to achieve the same.

my system details:
Ubuntu : 16.04 LTS, 
LXC version : 2.0.8

the shell script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
##Start the container if it is stopped
lxc-start -n nameofthecontainer
```

My intention is to keep the container running all the time, hence looking for some notification when the container is stopped so that I can restart.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Verified with latest LXC version 3.0.1 and hooks are working as expected. The issue was older LXC version